# Is there some sort of Java-Registry?

Tags: java, registry, preferences

Is there some sort of Registry which comes with JRE and doesn't change with a JRE-Update?
I want to save some values - like Window-Positions, used Paths or License - but don't want to save them into a file.

An alternative would be an encrypted-file (for example a license-file) or a xml-file (for example an option-file).

Comment: *Why* don't you want to save them in a file? The Java preferences API (which I believe uses files) is the right way to go for this.

Comment: @JonSkeet: the Java Preferences API uses a platform dependent storage. So it uses the registry on Windows and config files on Linux/Unix.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the correction. It's been a while since I've looked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Java Preferences API for this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html

But I agree with Jon Skeet that storing this kind of things in a file is better. It is easier to work with when e.g. changing the computer or synchronizing this between different computers.

You could use a `Properties` file for that.

Comment: Thanks @a-horse-with-no-name and Jon Skeet, i'll look into Properties-files and the Java preferences API, but i think i'll use a Properties-file and try to encrypt it if necessary.